# how to make selectable limit on tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a trouble solving out this fiddle. When i put limits i am not able to select any boxes.
Any suggestions??

I have make the following fiddle to show the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/28

```
  $(function() {
    $(".selectable").selectable({
 filter: "td.cs:lt(4)",

      stop: function(){
        var result = $("#select-result").empty();
        var result2 = $("#result2");
      $('.ui-selecting:gt(31)').removeClass("ui-selecting");

     $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(){

          var cabbage = this.id + ', ';
          result.append(cabbage);
        });

        var newInputResult = $('#select-result').text(); 
            newInputResult = newInputResult.substring(0, newInputResult.length - 1);
            result2.val(newInputResult); 
      }
    });
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: With limits you meas setting a filter?

Comment: yes i set the filter but when i try to select the boxes bellow it won't select them

Comment: Well you filtered on the first 4 tds, so the result is right. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i don't want only the first 4 i would like to select any 4 on a table

Comment: Do you mean, you want to allow only a maximum of 'N' boxes to be selectable?

Comment: repost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054166/how-do-i-limit-selectable-elements-using-jquery-ui-selectable

Comment: i have tried to use this example that you send me but i can't manage to add it in my code i am still begginer

Comment: No, after looking closer, I dont think that post ever got answered properly.  I will look into your question now

Comment: also the don't stay selected when i select them

Comment: this is exaclty what i wanted but something is wrong when i select.when selecting  boxes to be like the first fiddle you send me. The are some deference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is another solution, it does not use JqueryUI but may be what you want anyway.  It basically toggles the class selected on clicked boxes, with a maximum of 4 being able to be selected.  I added the class selected to your css

```
$(".cs").click(function(){
 var numItems = $('.selected').length   
if(numItems < 4) {          
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");   
}   

if(numItems == 4 && $(this).hasClass("selected")) {

    $(this).removeClass("selected"); 
}           

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NHnU5/1/

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to achieve? Which limits are you talking about? If you use `lt(4)`in the `filter`, you are asking `selectable` that only first 4 boxes are allowed to be selected.

I have modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/40/, you will see the following added:-

```
     if($(".ui-selected").length>4)
          {
     $(".ui-selected", this).each(function(i,e){
         if(i>3)
         {
         $(this).removeClass("ui-selected");
         }
     });   
return;              
          }
```

This will now select a maximum of 4 boxes..

UPDATE: Disallowing during they are being selected:- http://jsfiddle.net/dw6Hf/43/

```
selecting: function(i,e){
                    if($(".ui-selecting").length>4)
          {
     $(".ui-selecting", this).each(function(i,e){
         if(i>3)
         {
         $(this).removeClass("ui-selecting");
         }
     });   
return;              
          }     
        },
```

Comment: Beyond this, if you want not to perform this removing of even 'ui-selecting' class, you will have to modify the jquery selectable plugin itself.